# Errors when calling powershell commands from cmd

Tags: powershell, batch-file, escaping, quoting

I'm trying to return value to my batch script.
In powershell this script works fine:

```
PS> (Get-Date -Date "9.04.2017" -Uformat "%w.%Y-%m-%d").Replace("0.", "7.")
7.2017-04-09
```

When i try from batch:

```
for /f %%a in ('powershell ^(Get-Date -Uformat "%%w.%%Y-%%m-%%d"^).Replace^(^'0.^', ^'7.^'^)') do set datestamp=%%a
echo %datestamp%
```

I get errors, but this script works fine:

```
for /f %%a in ('powershell ^(get-date^).DayOfWeek') do set weekday=%%a
for /f %%a in ('powershell Get-Date -Uformat "%%u.%weekday%.%%Y-%%m-%%d"') do set datestamp=%%a
echo %datestamp%
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"I have an error"* So, what does it say?

Comment: also : I can't think of any reason why you would try to do this from batch?

Comment: I have a big batch script, where I need only one powershell call. Maybe later I''rewrite the script to powershell.

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60442926/45375

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to avoid need of escaping single quotes use `useback` parameter.Put everything in double quotes to avoid need of escaping brackets (and mind that -UFormat also accepts single quotes for the format):

```
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`"powershell (Get-Date -Uformat '%%w.%%Y-%%m-%%d').Replace('0.', '7.')"`) do set datestamp=%%a
echo %datestamp%
```

Comment: `usebackq` is a great idea, but I suggest wrapping only the (implied) `-Command` argument (the string containing the PowerShell commands) in `"..."`: `for /f "usebackq" %%a in (\`powershell -Command "(Get-Date -Uformat '%%w.%%Y-%%m-%%d').Replace('0.', '7.')"\`) do set datestamp=%%a`. If you need to _embed_ `"` chars. inside the command string, use `\""` in _Windows PowerShell_ (`powershell.exe`) or, more simply and robustly, `""` in _PowerShell [Core] 6+_ (`pwsh.exe`).

Answer (score 2):

I've found my mistake. I need to escape comma-character.
Now it looks strange, but works.

```
for /f %%a in ('powershell ^(Get-Date  -Date "9.04.2017" -Uformat "%%w.%%Y-%%m-%%d"^).Replace^(^'0.^'^,^'7.^'^)') do set datestamp=%%a
echo %datestamp%
```

Comment: comma is a standard delimiter in batch files as long as `<space>`,`<tab>`,`,`,`;` and `=` and needs to be escaped in for loops.

Comment: To rephrase @npocmaka's helpful comment: all the characters mentioned function as _argument separators_.