# Passing Powershell variable to Windows Batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, variables, command-line

Due to restrictions around my project and how this is being deployed, I need to run a powershell command in a batch file and echo a variable from the powershell script. This scripts retrieves a model number from a TV over RS-232 and returns the model in HEX.

I wrote the script and meticulously condensed it to one line that runs. I can even 'powershell -command "[myCondensedScript]"' in the command line and it works great

```
for /F %%a in ('powershell.exe -command "$port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1, 9600, none, 8, one;[byte[]] $reqSerial = 1,48,65,48,65,48,54,2,67,50,49,55,3,112,13;[byte[]] $reqModel = 0x01,0x30,0x41,0x30,0x41,0x30,0x36,0x02,0x43,0x32,0x31,0x37,0x03,0x70,0x0D;[byte[]] $response = '';[byte[]] $readData = '';$port.DTREnable = $True;$port.Open();$port.Write($reqModel, 0, $reqModel.Count);$x=0;do {$x++;$readData = $port.ReadChar();If($x -eq 13 -or $x -eq 14 -or $x -eq 15 -or $x -eq 16 -or $x -eq 17 -or $x -eq 18 -or $x -eq 19 -or $x -eq 20 -or $x -eq 21) {$response += $readData;};}while($response.Length -ne 9);$port.Close();$hexResponse = $response.forEach([char]);$hexResponseString = [string]$hexResponse;$hexResponseString = $hexResponseString.replace(' ','');$finalHex = $hexResponseString+0;Write-Host $finalHex;"^; (Get-Variable -ValueOnly -Name finalHex^).value') do set HexCode=%%a

echo %HexCode%
```

The output is simply

```
   echo +
```

The expected output would be

```
563332330
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing with the variable, as I'm not terribly skilled with variables and batch files. I have googled extensively and found this page to be somewhat helpful https://ss64.com/nt/for.html I just don't understand how I assign %%a to the exact variable I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command has unescaped embedded `'` characters in the context of the enclosing `'...'` string, which won't work.

Instead, **use the `usebackq` parsing option** and **enclose the command in `` `...` ``**, which simplifies quoting and escaping.

The following sample command demonstrate the technique (to try this at the `cmd.exe` prompt instead of from a batch file, replace `%%a` with `%a`):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`
  powershell -c "$finalHex = '0x68 0x69' -replace '0x| '; $finalHex"
`) do set "HexNum=%%a"
echo %HexNum%
```

The above prints the following, proving that embedded `"..."`, `'...'`, and `;` worked as-is (in the context of using `"..."` for the enclosing quoting around the PowerShell command passed to `-c` (`-Command`) as a whole, which prevents `cmd.exe` from interpreting the contents):

```
6969
```

---

To summarize the **`usebackq` rules with [PowerShell's CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell.exe)**:

- Pass the PowerShell commands enclosed in `"..."` *as a whole* to the `-c` / `-Command` parameter (which is *implied* in *Windows PowerShell*, but *required* in PowerShell [Core] 6+).

  - Since `cmd.exe` doesn't interpret the contents of `"..."` strings (except `%...%` environment-variable references), `cmd.exe` metacharacters (characters with special syntactic meaning, e.g., `&`) can be used as-is.
- Single quotes (`'`) can be used as-is.
- If you need to *embed* double quotes (`"`) inside the overall `"..."` command string:

  - In PowerShell [Core] 6+ (`pwsh.exe`), use `""`.
  - In Windows PowerShell (`powershell.exe`), use `\""`, but note that string-internal whitespace will then be *normalized* (folded into a *single* space); `\"` avoids that, but then requires you to `^`-escape any `cmd.exe` metacharacters such as `&`.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`
  REM In PowerShell [Core] 6+ (pwsh.exe), use "" instead of \""
  powershell -noprofile -c "(\""hi &    there\"").Replace('i', '@')"
`) do @echo [%%i]
```

The above yields (note the normalized whitespace; in PowerShell [Core] 6+ with `""` this wouldn't happen):

```
[hi & there]
```

---

As for **your specific command**:

- Remove the `^` (carets), as they are no longer needed with the `` `...` `` quoting; enclose the commands passed to `powershell -c` *as a whole* in `"..."`.
- Prevent pollution of the output stream to make sure that only the value of interest is returned, which means:

  - Remove the `Write-Host` command.
  - Place `$null = ...` before the `$port.Open()`, `$port.Write(...)`, `$port.Close()` calls to make sure that they do not *implicitly* create output (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) for an explanation).
- Simply use `$finalHex` *by itself* as the last statement in order to output it (no need for `(Get-Variable ...)`).

Answer (score 0):

I parsed the powershell part of it.  The two carets, ^, at the end do not make sense to me. Can you explain the point of them? Look at the last line a little closer.

**`# Removed " from "$Port below`**

```
$port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1, 9600, none, 8, one;
[byte[]] $reqSerial = 1,48,65,48,65,48,54,2,67,50,49,55,3,112,13;
[byte[]] $reqModel = 0x01,0x30,0x41,0x30,0x41,0x30,0x36,0x02,0x43,0x32,0x31,0x37,0x03,0x70,0x0D;
[byte[]] $response = '';[byte[]] $readData = '';$port.DTREnable = $True;
$port.Open();
$port.Write($reqModel, 0, $reqModel.Count);$x=0;

do {$x++;$readData = $port.ReadChar();

    If($x -eq 13 -or $x -eq 14 -or $x -eq 15 -or $x -eq 16 -or $x -eq 17 -or $x -eq 18 -or $x -eq 19 -or $x -eq 20 -or $x -eq 21) 
    {$response += $readData;};

}
while($response.Length -ne 9);
$port.Close();

$hexResponse = $response.forEach([char]);
$hexResponseString = [string]$hexResponse;
$hexResponseString = $hexResponseString.replace(' ','');
$finalHex = $hexResponseString+0;
Write-Host $finalHex;"^; (Get-Variable -ValueOnly -Name finalHex^).value
```

Comment: Make the powershell part work in powershell.  Look into the "-EncodedCommand" for Powershell.exe

Comment: Great Question! I took that piece from a previously deployed script (not written by me, but works) and I assumed the carets were there to escape the semi-colon ; and end paren ). What vexes me is there's no caret for the begin paren (. I tried removing them and adding one for the begin paren, but to no avail. I left them since it's worked in previous deployments. Unfortunately the people that did the previous deployments are no longer here. :(

Answer (score 0):

If this works in powershell then you can try to put it back into the command line you have.

```
$port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1, 9600, none, 8, one;
[byte[]] $reqSerial = 1,48,65,48,65,48,54,2,67,50,49,55,3,112,13;
[byte[]] $reqModel = 0x01,0x30,0x41,0x30,0x41,0x30,0x36,0x02,0x43,0x32,0x31,0x37,0x03,0x70,0x0D;
[byte[]] $response = '';[byte[]] $readData = '';$port.DTREnable = $True;
$port.Open();
$port.Write($reqModel, 0, $reqModel.Count);
$x=0;

do {$x++;$readData = $port.ReadChar();

    If($x -eq 13 -or $x -eq 14 -or $x -eq 15 -or $x -eq 16 -or $x -eq 17 -or $x -eq 18 -or $x -eq 19 -or $x -eq 20 -or $x -eq 21) 
    {$response += $readData;};

}
while($response.Length -ne 9);
$port.Close();

$hexResponse = $response.forEach([char]);
$hexResponseString = [string]$hexResponse;
$hexResponseString = $hexResponseString.replace(' ','');
$finalHex = $hexResponseString+0;
(Get-Variable -ValueOnly -Name finalHex).value
```